# How to scrape certain amount of characters from line python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, webautomation

So I am quite new to python and coding in general and I am learning python so I can automate tasks. I want to scrape data into a csv and then later use this csv to upload these products to a website. However, from the website that I am scraping. It has very long titles and descriptions. But the website I am uploading to has a character limit.

So what is the best way to approach this with python?

- Is there a way I can limit the characters that are scraped? so when scraping the data only the first 45 characters are copied?
- Or can I scrape like normal but then format the csv file to keep the first x amount of characters and how could I do this?
- Lastly, or can I limit the amount of characters being pasted when filling the data into the website I am uploading to?

Please kindly share if any of these are possible and what would be the fasted and easiest way to perform this?

looking forward to any help!

Comment: Use string slicing?

Comment: use `text[:45]` or module `textwrap` which keeps full words and adds `[...]` - ie, `textwrap.shorten('Hello World of Python', 17)` gives `Hello World [...]`

Comment: Did my solution resolve your problem?

Comment: @furas thank you for your answer! This worked perfectly also. But I have a questions for the textwrap module. if I wanted to remove the [...] when printing the line from csv. Is this possible?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Cheers for guiding me to the right way!

Comment: it is a string so you can use any string-function to modify it - ie`text = text.replace(" [...]", "")` or remove last 6 chars `text = text[:-6]`. But first you could check if it added `[...]` - `if "[...]" in text:`

Comment: @furas I checked and it was added and this worked perfectly. I really appreciate it. This was very very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has standard module `textwrap` which can keep full words and add `[...]` at the end.

```
import textwrap

textwrap.shorten('Hello World of Python', 17)
```

gives

```
'Hello World [...]'
```

---

If you don't want `[...]` then you can use own `placeholder` but it needs to use

```
import textwrap

w = textwrap.TextWrapper(placeholder='', width=17, max_lines=1)

w.fill('Hello World of Python')
```

which gives

```
'Hello World of'
```

And using `placeholder=', etc.'`

```
import textwrap

w = textwrap.TextWrapper(placeholder=', etc.', width=17, max_lines=1)

w.fill('Hello World of Python')
```

you can get

```
'Hello World, etc.'
```

---

You can get full path to source code and check how it works

```
import textwrap

print( textwrap.__file__ )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest cutting the too long strings.
I mean after scraping the data, in case your string is too long - cut out the string tail.
For example if your scraped string is named `data` and you need to limit its length to 50 you can do the following:

```py
data = data[:50]
```